Positiveness of a solution of a system of elliptical equations
Given $u \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$, suppose there exists a unique $B(u) \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ weak solution of
$$
-\Delta v + V(x) v = u, \mathbb{R}^N,
$$
where $V$ is a suitable weight. Let $N \geq 3$ and consider $f(t) := |t|^{p-2}t$,  for $2 < p < 2^\ast$. Now define the truncation $\tilde{f}(t) = f(t)$ if $t \geq 0$ and $\tilde{f}(t) = 0$ if $t < 0$.
Also suppose we have found a weak solution for the problem
$$
-\Delta u + V(x)B(u) = Q(x)\tilde{f}(u),
$$
where $Q$ is another weight.
Is it possible to know the sign of $u$? That is, is it possible to show that $u^- = 0$?
